# Simple Client Sever application in C #

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient

I am trying to build a simple client server application where the server keeps listening and the client can send messages. I am using http://brunov.info/blog/2013/02/09/tcpip-client-server-application-exchange-with-string-messages/ as a reference. However when i type in on console on the client.exe no message goes to the server and the program hangs up. What am i doing wrong. Please advice.

Regards

Here is my Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ucSim1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loaclAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            var tcpListener = new TcpListener(loaclAddress, 81);
            tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection");

                var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Client Accepted");

                Thread thread = new Thread(() => ClientSession(tcpClient))
                {
                    IsBackground = true
                };

                thread.Start();
                Console.WriteLine( "Client Session thread started");

            }

        }

        private static bool tryRead(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int bytesRead;
            while (count > 0 && (bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0)
            {
                offset += bytesRead;
                count -= bytesRead;
            }
            return count == 0;
        }



        private static void ClientSession(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            const int totalByteBuffer = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(networkStream, totalByteBuffer))
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!tryRead(bufferedStream, buffer, 0, 1))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    byte messageLen = buffer[0];
                    if (!tryRead(bufferedStream, buffer, 1, messageLen))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,1,messageLen);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Recieved: {0}", message);

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace ucSim2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] msg2ByteArray(string message, Encoding enc)
        {
            var byteCount = enc.GetByteCount(message);
            if (byteCount > byte.MaxValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Message size is greater than 255 bytes in the provided encoding");
            }
            var byteArray = new byte[byteCount+1];
            byteArray[0] = (byte)byteCount;
            enc.GetBytes(message,0,message.Length,byteArray,1);
            return byteArray;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String message;
            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 81);
                using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(networkStream))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                        Console.WriteLine("Write Message");
                        message = Console.ReadLine();
                        var byteArray = msg2ByteArray(message, Encoding.ASCII);
                        bufferedStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**i figured it out just after i posted the question...should have spent some more time before jumping the gun and posting the question...appologies**

Comment: Did you debug your server code? WHere did it stop working?

Comment: i figured it out...the buffer was not clear...

Comment: i  figured it out just after i posted the question...should have spent some more time before jumping the gun and posting the question...appologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sending a message, you should call the [`Flush()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.flush.aspx):

```
bufferedStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
bufferedStream.Flush(); // add this line
```

Comment: yes...thanks...i also figured it out just after i posted the question...should have spent some more time before jumping the gun and posting the question...appologies

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what you want to do with the BufferedStream, but when you write on the networkStream, it works:

```
while (true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    Console.WriteLine("Write Message");
    message = Console.ReadLine();
    var byteArray = msg2ByteArray(message, Encoding.ASCII);
    networkStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

and

```
if (!tryRead(networkStream, buffer, 0, 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Message, process canceled.");
    break;
}
byte messageLen = buffer[0];
if (!tryRead(bufferedStream, buffer, 1, messageLen))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Message, process canceled.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i will try with network streams as well